# Is there a dedicated home page for SO Jobs?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

Based on the ad for a job on the SO homepage, I was browsing through some of the job offerings available. At one point, I had browsed too deep and wanted to start fresh. So out of habit, I click on the logo.

[image: Nav bar logo]

And I am taken to the SO homepage (not the jobs homepage).

---

I checked the URL of job and it read `stackoverlfow.com/jobs/<id>`.

I figured maybe if I go the dedicated jobs portal I might find the functionality I am looking for. I go to `jobs.stackoverflow.com` and am redirected to `stackoverflow.com/jobs`

---

I have vague memories of there being a separate jobs network and not a sub-route of SO. Am I not recollecting correctly?

If one existed, was it removed?

If one did not exist, shouldn't there be one?

Comment: You can click on the burger menu (to the left of the logo) and a menu will pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jobs is part of and hosted under the same domain as Stack Overflow.

The jobs home page link can be found in the left sidebar, but you've hidden it.